# How to bind to javascript events after the DOM changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, effects

I have a function that binds to a tr tag to provide a mouseover effect like this:

> $(".grid tr").bind("mouseenter",
>   function () {
>   $(this).addClass("hover");
>   }).bind("mouseleave", function () {
>   $(this).removeClass("hover"); });

The problem is the grid is loaded via ajax when paging occurs, or filtering etc. This causes the grid to be completely replaced and all the event bindings to fail. Is there a way to bind to an event that automatically attaches to matching elements even when the DOM changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`$.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is what you want:

```
$(".grid tr").live("mouseenter", function () { $(this).addClass("hover"); }).bind("mouseleave", function () { $(this).removeClass("hover"); });
```

Comment: While live() will fix the problem, it's very inefficient. It's better to hook into the success event of the ajax call and update the applicable dom nodes with the new event

Answer (score 3):

Please use `.on()` from now on, as `.live()` is deprecated in jQuery as it is inefficient.

```
$(".grid tr")
    .on("mouseenter", function () { $(this).addClass("hover"); })
    .on("mouseleave", function () { $(this).removeClass("hover"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use [`$.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

More info: [what is the best practice of binding jQuery click event to each anchor tag on every row of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124515/what-is-the-best-practice-of-binding-jquery-click-event-to-each-anchor-tag-on-eve)