# what is the best practice of binding jQuery click event to each anchor tag on every row of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a grid (just html table) that lists users and you can delete a specific user by clicking on delete link. The usual way I do is

```
<% foreach (var user in Model.Users) {%>
<tr >
  <td align="right"><%= user.Name %></td>
  <td><%= user.Level %></td>
  <td align="center">
    <a href="#" onclick="return deleteUser('<%= user.Name %>');">
        <%= Html.Image("trash.gif") %>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
<% )%>
```

but I want to attach click event to the link in a non-obtrusive way. I mean, I do not want to specify javascript method inside the tag. I am not sure what is the best way to achieve it with jQuery, binding multiple multiple anchor tags with parameter passing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method on the table:

```
$('#tableId').delegate('a', 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the user name
    deleteUser($(this).closest('tr').children(':first').text());
    // or give the cell that contains the name a class
    // deleteUser($(this).closest('tr').children('.name').text());
});
```

This way, you only register **one** event handler.

Comment: Doesn't jQuery internally bind `onclick` for each `a` element?

Comment: @sje397: No, a single handler is bound once to #tableId and event bubbling will fire the handler bound to the table.

Comment: @John Strickler: I am not so sure that is the case. The jQuery API states that using delegate like this is the equivalent to $("tableId").each($("a", this).live("click", function() { ... }); }); e.g. handlers would be attached for each anchor found and not just to #tableId.

Comment: @300 baud: No,@John is right. It is only one event handler... that it is *equivalent*, in terms of effect, to `live`, dos not mean that it works the same way internally (besides that, `live` also only uses one event handler and catches bubbling events). For more information about event delegation, watch [this talk](http://loft.bocoup.com/john-resig-advanced-jquery/) by John Resig, at 23m40s.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Thanks for the link. John Resig's explanation of delegate() suggests that the click event handler would be attached to the table itself and whenever the table is clicked a determination is made at that point as to whether it matches the selector passed into the delegate call. This would be consistent with what you and John Strickler have stated. If this is the case, I would suggest that the API documentation can be misleading as it never uses the phrase "in terms of effect" as you did. It simply says "is equivalent to the following code" and then shows the each iterator.

Comment: @Felix Kling: BTW, I had upvoted your answer prior to my comment. I was only disputing how the delegate() handler works. Now that I have been enlightened I would upvote again but SO prevents voter fraud.

Answer (score 1):

For performance and optimization you can attach the click handler to that table:

```
<table id="grid">
<% foreach (var user in Model.Users) {%>
<tr >
  <td class="name"><%= user.Name %></td>
  <td><%= user.Level %></td>
  <td align="center">
    <a href="#" class="delete">
        <%= Html.Image("trash.gif") %>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
<% )%>
</table>

$('#grid').click(function(e){
   var source = $(e.target);
   if(source.is('.delete')){ //or source.hasClass('delete') 
      var user = source.closest('tr').find('td.name').text();
      deleteUser(user);
      e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```